# I used the query by nested and want to in join operation

Tags: mysql

This code taking more time or crashed because data is more than 2000. please suggest me new query.

This query is for multilevel. My database increases daily. If I have 2M data.... thannnn...

help me.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT emp_id 
FROM emp 
WHERE (referral IN (SELECT emp_id FROM emp 
                    WHERE referral IN (SELECT emp_id FROM emp  
                                       WHERE referral IN (SELECT emp_id FROM emp 
                                                          WHERE referral ='2') 
                                      )
                   ) 
   OR referral IN (SELECT emp_id FROM emp 
                   WHERE referral IN (SELECT emp_id FROM emp 
                                      WHERE referral = '2')
                  ) 
   OR referral IN (SELECT emp_id FROM emp WHERE referral ='2'))
```

I'm using php and mysqli.

Comment: Explain that query please. There's a lot ways to do that but first for all, explain that query and make sure you are indexing it correctly

Comment: I want to get data where 1st emp_id in refferal than the result have some emp_id than this result emp id's in refferal then the result get two set than the result have emp_id than this emp_id's in refferal

Comment: Edit your question and add all the neccesary info to help you. (show the table structure and explain better what you want to do)

Comment: How do i edit my question. There is no option show for edit . I'm new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I mean the next query can solve the problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp_id 
FROM emp 
LEFT JOIN emp as ref1 ON emp.referral = ref1.emp_id
LEFT JOIN emp as ref2 ON ref1.referral = ref2.emp_id
LEFT JOIN emp as ref3 ON ref2.referral = ref3.emp_id
WHERE 
    ref1.referral ='2' OR
    ref2.referral ='2' OR
    ref3.referral ='2';
```